# Is there word for entrepreneurship which is related to only IT(Software, Web Design, Online marketing, Blogging, etc)?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there word for entrepreneurship which is related to only IT(Software, Web Design, Online marketing, Blogging, etc)?

Can I use as **'IT Entrepreneurship'**?

Comment: Tech entrepreneurship?

Comment: @k1eran Seems like Tech Entrepreneurship is best...........

Comment: added it as an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Tech** Entrepreneurship*

cambridge.org uses *entrepreneurs* as an example in its definition of **tech**:

> **tech**
> abbreviation for technology :
> *tech entrepreneurs*
>
> devices that use computer technology:
> *They have all the latest tech.*
> *wearable tech*
>
> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tech

Answer (score 0):

"IT entrepreneurship" would be accurate. These days, however, it's common to refer to such businesses simply as startups, which often implies some sort of IT aspect.

Answer (score 0):

**Digipreneur**

[Example 1](https://www.meetup.com/Jakarta-Online-Entrepreneurs-Community/messages/boards/thread/49842542):

> Digipreneur or "Digital Entrepreneur" is an entrepreneur who runs their business in the digital world (...)

[Example 2](http://www.nurturetalent.com/product/digipreneur-digital-marketing-workshop-aaruush-srm-university-chennai/):

> (...) IIT-IIM alum and founder of Nurture Talent will be conducting a 2 day hands on, practical workshop on digital marketing covering aspects related to internet marketing, social media marketing, search engine optimization, google analytics, ecommerce ventures, blogging, content publishing, whatsapp marketing, missed call marketing and entrepreneurship.

See many other examples on google search:

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=digipreneur

And visit this interesting blog site which also suggests this word has been around for at least 7 years (see article date):

http://digipreneurs.blogspot.in

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This phrase will be used in under the logo of company. So it might hard to understand "Digipreneur" for most of the users in just second??? But from your answer and a comment I thought to use **"Tech Entrepreneurship"** or **"Digital Entrepreneurship"**

Comment: It might certainly make sense to use 2 words that clearly convey the meaning, @Donkey King.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that *techpreneur* has been submitted to Collins as a new word suggestion:

> **techpreneur**
>   A entrepreneur who starts and manages their own technology business
>   [- Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/7880/Techpreneur)

I'd prefer the two-word alternative *technology entrepreneur*, though.